# What's a common way to refer to the algae that is attached to the bottom of a stream/river?

Tags: single-word-requests, plant-physiology

I'm referring to this:

[image]

What's a common name to refer to it? Or is algae common enough? (I know *seaweed* isn't very proper since it's not in the sea).

Comment: Not an answer, but I've always called it *ewww* and then *green slimy stuff*. Moss might work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is [*filamentous algae.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=filamentous+algae&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=attpUpOyBaX12wXrkIDICQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1408&bih=658) Or more specifically, *filamentous green algae*.

You could just call it *algae*.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macrophyte),

> A macrophyte is an aquatic plant that grows in or near water and is either emergent, submergent, or floating

so the term *macrophyte* could be used.  But for a non-technical audience, a term like *water plants* or *mossy water plants*   might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

*Waterweed* (or just *weed* if the context is clear enough) seems the best choice if you don't want to be technical.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the crowd-sourced online resource called the Free Dictionary:

> [*Conferva*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conferva) algae 1. (Plants) any of various threadlike green algae, esp any of the genus Tribonema, typically occurring in fresh water [C18: from Latin: a water plant, from confervēre to grow together, heal, literally: to seethe, from fervēre to boil; named with reference to its reputed healing properties]